# Edit the innerRadius of D3 Sunburst visualization

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, sunburst-diagram

How can I change the radius of the innermost circle of the Sunburst visualization? See following example: (http://bl.ocks.org/d/910126/ - notice how large is central area; can it be smaller?)

[image]

Also, is it possible to define different heights for all the layers in the Sunburst?

Answer (score 8):

`Yes`, it is possible.

---

### Base Example

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BmW2q/)

[image]

---

### Custom layer height 1

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QDP9H/)

[image]

---

### Custom layer height 2

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hq4ef/)

[image]

---

### Custom layer height 3

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gq7GR/)

[image]

Comment: can you please explain what you did to modify each of these examples?  i appreciate the code examples, but it's difficult to figure out the differences (and the logic) by looking at code in different windows.  thanks!

Comment: Can you make an example with v4 version of the d3.js library?

Answer (score 2):

I've just compared the examples above so can't claim any great skill\knowledge here but all the changes are in this section:

```
var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .startAngle(function(d) { return d.x; })
    .endAngle(function(d) { return d.x + d.dx; })
    .innerRadius(function(d) { return radius * Math.sqrt(d.y) / 10; })
    .outerRadius(function(d) { return radius * Math.sqrt(d.y + d.dy) / 10; });
```

The effects are interesting but not quite what I was looking for when I found this question\answer. I wanted to be able to control the size of each layer\ring individually really. Anyway... hope this picking apart of the jsfiddles above helps someone else.